# How to consume a iis hosted wcf service from asp.net2.0

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to consume WCF service using asp.net2.0

Here are some details:

1) WCF service hosted on different server IIS

URL : http://myserver/Service.svc

2) Web.config

```
bindings>
wsHttpBinding>
binding name="ServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/
/binding>
/wsHttpBinding>
/bindings>
services>
service name="MYNameSpace.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"
endpoint name="ServiceEndPoint" address="http://myserver/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.IService"/
/service
```

3) asp.net page

```
asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        Services
            asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Service.svc" /
        /Services
        Scripts
            asp:ScriptReference Path="~/myjs.js" /
        /Scripts
    /asp:ScriptManager
```

4) myjs.js

```
MYNameSpace.IService.MyMethod();
```

*** here it throws error that 'MyNameSpace' is not defined.

Everything works fine on my local machine.
Problem when I try to consume from asp.net2.0 application

Any inputs will be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try reformulating your question. It is really not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Editor is not taking '<' in the code that I pasted.

Comment: Call a IIS hosted WCF(different machine) service from asp.net2.0(work machine) using javascript.

Comment: The 1 0 1 0 1 0 icon allows you to paste code. Try using that with your code.

Anyway, how are you trying to call the WCF? Using a javascript library like MS AJAX or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article - [Exposing WCF Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514961.aspx). Looks like you may be missing the ServiceContract attribute.